# Google is reporting a 5xx server error for a page that changed URL

Tags: google-search-console, url, migration, http-code-500, url-removal

I had a page `/example` that now changed its URL to `/example-us`.

The following figure from Google Search Console shows an error occurred because that webpage no longer exists now and the URL is changed. How I can tell Google that page was removed from my site?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you setup 301 redirection from `/example` to `/example-us` ?  Or what technology you're using it on your site ? So you can get perfect solution on how to implement 301 redirection on xyz.

Comment: @Goyllo no just remove page and create another one with other URL. this is a basic wrong works. Angular 7 + Node.JS /// i.e this is a wrong name and correct the name (so the url changed)

Comment: What we server?  Angular and node are both frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that your URL change is unrelated to the error.

A 500x error usually means a server side processing error, like unable to render the page or there's bug in the server side code on the page (PHP, ASPX, etc).  400x errors typically mean the page doesn't exist.

Since Google is showing you a 500 error, are you sure it's because the file doesn't exist?  You said you changed the URL.  Did you rename the file or something that would cause your server to not know how to render the file?  Could the old file still exist, but when Google tries to crawl it, the server can't process because of a code change?

Comment: again I tell the problem. in few weeks ago our page is called examples some days ago that page is removed and another page with name example-us is created.

Comment: please see my updates in adding figure to question

Comment: @MaryamM I see your change, but that doesn't change the nature of the error code.  There's nothing there saying that Google cannot find the file (a 404 error) on your server, only that the web server returned an error (500 - an internal server error).  The key is the error code.  Here's a list of the various HTTP codes and their meanings - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes